# ASP.MVC3 is client side validation enabled by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

In my Layout page, i have the following links to the validation Javascript files,

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"type="text/javascript"> </script>
         <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My entities are decorated with validation attributes like

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a customer name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

Then in my view i have validation messages specified after the update fields like so

```
<div class="label-for">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)</div>
<div class="editor">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName)</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
```

The validation is working however its not on the client side, the way i understand this is that error messages should be displayed when one of the fields is left blank afer tabbing to another field, is there anything else required to get client side validation working?

Comment: Do you have the appsettings "ClientValidationEnabled" and "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" set to true in your web.config file? (They should be by default).

Comment: I am setting these to true in the start method of the global ASAX file, however i will try doing tis in the web config instead.

Comment: Yes they are enabled in the web config as you correctly stated this must be default.

Comment: Hmm, ok. It _should_ work then. Could you try a very simple example?

Comment: Not sure what i can do different to what ive done above? ive added the required atrribute to the entity properties, the validation messages are added in the view and the scripts are added in the head section of the layout page. Validation messages are only displayed after clicking the save button??

Comment: I'd open a new project and test with the minimum amount of code and see if you can find a difference between that and your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC there were some incompatibilities between `jquery` and `jquery.validate` versions. You seem to be using an old version of jquery 1.4.4. Try updating with the latest. For example install the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/03/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) and create a new ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio which will get you the proper versions of the following scripts: jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.

Answer (score 0):

May be this work: Make sure that in your web.config file, you set "ClientValidationEnabled" to "True"

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

NOTE: In MVC3 web project, there were two web.config files one under "View" folder another under root web project. make sure that the one in the root does not override the other.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery validation has nothing to do with your validation mechanism. Maybe Microsoft.Ajax.Validation should be the responsible. But to use jquery.validation, you should write code. That's all. It doesn't do anything out of the box.

Comment: strange as in Steve Sandersons Pro Asp.Net MVC3 framework book it states "MVC client side validation is based upon Jquery and is enabled by default when the relevant scripts are added"

Comment: Well, I didn't know about that book, and I also haven't seen it in action for myself. Seems that it's just a theory.

Comment: -1, You can use jquery validation with the built in validation in asp.net mvc. No need to write the client side validation code by hand.

Comment: -1 because I've used this in MVC3 and the comment is flat out wrong. You DO use jQuery and some of the DataAnnotations have built in validators.