# Putting Html.ValidationMessageFor in a nice list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I've got a bunch of validationmessages that I want to stack under eachother.
So I tried 2 options.
`<br />` after each validation, sadly this generates an empty white space between each validation even if there is none.

Second one I tried is `<ul> <li></li> </ul>`.
It has the same result as the 
 one sadly.

Any other way I can make a list of my validationerrors without a white space inbetween if there is no error?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary.aspx)? It is designed for the exact scenario that you describe.

Razor example:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the form errors and try again.")
```

Note, there is an optional first parameter to toggle the display of the property errors:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the form errors and try again.")
```

In MVC, the errors are presented client side if Client Validation is enabled.

Comment: I have, but that's only for server side validation and not client side validation or is it? :D

Comment: Thx but I already have the validationSummary. But the summary only shows the errors when it does a post back. The jquery errors are the ones that I want listed.

Comment: Can you confirm ClientValidation is enabled?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608473/asp-mvc3-is-client-side-validation-enabled-by-default

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. But it's okay. I'll find another way or let it be. It's only a cosmetic problem :D